# Call API based on page count

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, pagination, android-volley

Please help me to solve api call based on page count in Wordpress rest api. 
http://www.thejavaprogrammer.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?page=1&per_page=10

As i have read pagination from below link :- 
http://blog.iamsuleiman.com/android-pagination-tutorial-getting-started-recyclerview/

So let me know any solution for this.

Comment: What is your means?

Comment: means u have ur question in ur mind but not in above question

Comment: suppose page count is 5 then it will load 50 items in recycler view. i want to fetch or call api based on page count and load these items in recycler view.

Comment: then u need to increase your count according to your page

Comment: initially it will load 10 items and then increasing items page by page on pull to refresh

Answer (score 0):

So you need to do increase count of your variable whenever you trying to hit api and do calculation according what you want:-

```
int count = 0;
@Override
public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
    super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

    int visibleItemCount = layoutManager.getChildCount();
    int totalItemCount = layoutManager.getItemCount();
    int firstVisibleItemPosition = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

    if (!isLoading() && !isLastPage()) {
        if ((visibleItemCount + firstVisibleItemPosition) >= totalItemCount
                && firstVisibleItemPosition >= 0) {
            count++;
            loadMoreItems();

        }
    }
}

public void loadMoreItems() {
    int numberPage = count * 10;
    String url = "http://www.thejavaprogrammer.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?page=1&per_page="+numberPage;
}
```

Or you can increase simple 10 count.

```
int count = 0;
public void loadMoreItems() {
     count = count + 10;
     String url = "http://www.thejavaprogrammer.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?page=1&per_page="+count;
}
```